# Adding posts to from form database categories

Tags: php, mysql, forms, categories

I have a form from where i add posts to my database table and i made categories in this table and i puted  in the "ADD POSTS" form an option to choose the category when i add the post. It works in my other website witch is just to try some new things but to my main project it doesnt and i use the same code with same tables names. Can someone check the code and tell me where is my mistake?

Thats my whole ADDposts form:

```
<?php
include 'includes/connect.php';

 if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    $time = time();
    $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
    $content = strip_tags($_POST['content']);
    $post_image= $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
    $image_tmp= $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];
    $q = "INSERT INTO posts(post_title,post_content,post_author,added,post_image) VALUES('$title','$content','Papazov','$time','$post_image')";
    mysql_query($q) or die (mysql_error());







    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include "hhh.html"; ?> <br /><br />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MatchZone</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
<form method="post" action="Addpost.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Заглавие: <input type="text" name="title" /><br/><br/>

<tr>
        <td align="right">Preview:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="preview" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
    <br />
    <br />


<tr>
        <td align="right">Сложи снимка: </td>
        <td><input type="file" name="image"></td>
</tr>
<br/><br/>
Категория: <select name="category">
    <?php 
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM categories") or die (mysql_error());
        while($c = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
            print '<option value="'.$c['cat_id'].'">'.$c['name'].'</option>\n';
        }

    ?>
</select><br />
<br />
<textarea class="ckeditor" name= "content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Добави" />
</form>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're using the same code that works on one server but not another, check your DB credentials.

Comment: i checked 10 times :S all is same

Comment: I think you're trying to run everything off the same file. If you are, then you need to change `action="Addpost.php"` to `action=""` from what I could tell. If not, then edit your question to seperate the files and their titles. It's hard to tell with one BIG body of code, yet that's what I make of it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you close the select tag? If you can show the part where you insert to the database would be of help

Comment: Thanks, but still I can't see where did you make the relation between the post and the category. What exactly is your problem? Isn't inserting? Isn't creating the relation? The select is not showing?

Comment: A possible issue here is the include 'includes/connect.php'; check the path of this file

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like you're trying to run everything off the same page.

If this is the case (which most likely is), then change `action="Addpost.php"` to `action=""`

Since you have `if(isset($_POST['add']))` near the top of your code,

and further below `<input type="submit" name="add" value="Добави" />` clearly being in the same page.

Comment: yes yes the relation ofcourse :D sorry i waste your time i just forgot to put the category into the request

Comment: I understand, and you didn't waste my time. I take it you found your solution then? @user3242513